# How to check if a server i connect to supports ECN (Explicit Congestion Notification)

Tags: networking, macos

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_Congestion_Notification

How do i check if a server i connect to supports ECN? I'm on OSX 10.11.5. What i'd like to know is what commands to use to see if a TCP connection to e.g. "google.com" can use ECN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single command that I am aware of that can tell you whether a web server is ECN capable, however you would be able to find out by running a tcpdump and checking whether the ECN bit has been set in the SYN/ACK response from the server (assuming you have fully enabled ECN).

Alternatively, you could write a [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html) script to perform a custom TCP handshake and find whether the ECN bit is set in the response.